# Auto change field when input value and add more fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Example input fields :**

First value of `From number` is set default = 1.

```
1st From: 1  |  To: 10  |  Price: 100  |  + Add more fields +
```

When I input 10 on `To number` and click Add more fields my form should be like:

```
1st From: 1   |  To: 10      |  Price: 100     |
2nd From: 11  |  To: (null)  |  Price: (null)  |  - Remove - + Add more fields +
```

**What I want :**

When I change first `To number` field to 11 it will auto live change a second `From number` to 12 like:

```
1st From: 1   |  To: 11      |  Price: 100     |
2nd From: 12  |  To: (null)  |  Price: (null)  |  - Remove - + Add more fields +
```

**CODE :**

**html**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <br> 
    <div>
    From:
    <input type="text" readonly="" name="from[]" class="from" value="1"> To:
    <input type="text" name="to[]" class="to" value="2"> Price:
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price">
    </div>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            var lastTo = parseInt($('.to:last').val(), 10);
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>From: <input type="text" name="from[]" class="from" value="' + (lastTo + 1) + '"> To: <input type="text" name="to[]" class="to"> Price: <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
```

My code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qew09rfk/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change only the next .from input text for the next fieldset, use this script to archieve your goal

```
$(wrapper).on("input", ".to", function(){    
    var nextFrom = $(this).parent().nextAll("div").first().children("input").first();
    if($(nextFrom).length){
      $(nextFrom).val(parseInt(this.value) + 1);      
    }     
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsq0oypn/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as below:

Add an `input event` to all `to inputs` and change the value of next all `from fields` accordingly:

```
$('.input_fields_wrap').on('input','input[name="to[]"]',function(e){
   var _this=$(this);
   var fromFields=_this.closest('div').nextAll('div').find('input[name="from[]"]');
   //get all the next from fields which is after current to field
   $.each($(fromFields),function(){
        $(this).val(parseInt(_this.val())+1);
   }) 
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qew09rfk/3/)**

> **Note -** This is not a full fledged solution but yea you can modify according to your requirements.

Comment: This solution have a bug, if you add more than two fieldsets and change the first .to input, the script change all .from field in the form

Comment: @xzegga.. That is why I have mentioned **This is not a full fledged solution but yea you can modify according to your requirements.** This just answers what OP has asked for.. In fact you cannot given an exact solution for this as the requirement has not been specified.. What if you add multiple fields, input all the to numbers and then go to top and change the first to? Then even your approach doesn't provide valid solution for such requirement! :)